# Android: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when passing the values

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception

I am getting this ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException  when i am trying to pass latitude and logitude

```
private String getId(String facebookUser,String lat, String expiryMinute, String messageId, String message, String referenceKey, String placeId) {

        lang = Utils.formatDouble(Constants.searchLocation.getLongitude());
        lat = Utils.formatDouble(Constants.searchLocation.getLatitude());
        String traceId = null;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        PostMethod post = null;
        try {

            NameValuePair[] params = null;
            NameValuePair param = new NameValuePair();

            if(Constants.isMessageForPosting){
                params = new NameValuePair[6];
                param.setName("gadget");
                param.setValue("gettraceid");
                params[0] = param;

                if(messageId == null || messageId.trim().isEmpty()){
                    messageId = "1";
                }
            }else{
                params = new NameValuePair[8];
                param.setName("gadget");
                param.setValue("getrequestid");
                params[0] = param;
                if(messageId == null || messageId.trim().isEmpty()){
                    messageId = "2";
                }
            }

            if(expiryMinute == null || expiryMinute.trim().isEmpty()){
                expiryMinute = "0";
            }

            param = new NameValuePair();
            param.setName("fbuserid");
            param.setValue(facebookUser);
            params[1] = param;


            param = new NameValuePair();
            param.setName("userid");
            param.setValue(Constants.USERID);
            params[2] = param;

            param.setName("expiryminute");
            param.setValue(expiryMinute);
            params[3] = param;

            param.setName("msgid");
            param.setValue(messageId);
            params[4] = param;

            param = new NameValuePair();
            param.setName("msg");
            param.setValue(message);
            params[5] = param;

            param = new NameValuePair();
            param.setName("lat");
            param.setValue(lat);
            params[9] = param;

            param = new NameValuePair();
            param.setName("lang");
            param.setValue(lang);
            params[10] = param;
        */  
            if(!Constants.isMessageForPosting){
                param = new NameValuePair();
                param.setName("referencekey");
                param.setValue(referenceKey);
                params[6] = param;

                param = new NameValuePair();
                param.setName("placeid");
                param.setValue(placeId);
                params[7] = param;
            }

            post.setQueryString(params);
        int statusCode = client.executeMethod(post);
            traceId = post.getResponseBodyAsString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "For Facebook Trace Id:", e);

        } finally {
            post.releaseConnection();
            post = null;
        }
        return Id;
    }
```

below is my stack trace

```
02-26 15:39:52.131: E/MainFragment(23117): For Facebook Trace Id:
02-26 15:39:52.131: E/MainFragment(23117): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=6; index=9
02-26 15:39:52.131: E/MainFragment(23117):  at org.appright.mycity.activity.MainFragment.getTraceId(MainFragment.java:291)
02-26 15:39:52.131: E/MainFragment(23117):  at org.appright.mycity.activity.MainFragment.access$7(MainFragment.java:225)
02-26 15:39:52.131: E/MainFragment(23117):  at org.appright.mycity.activity.MainFragment$PostFBMessage.doInBackground(MainFragment.java:553)
02-26 15:39:52.131: E/MainFragment(23117):  at org.appright.mycity.activity.MainFragment$PostFBMessage.doInBackground(MainFragment.java:1)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are declaring params variable with either 6 element or 8 element. but at later on you are accessing the 8th & 9th element, which is wrong.

Solution:

Either you should use static array size wih 10 element or use ArrayList Class.

Comment: can u please tell me how to pass my lat and long ?

Comment: where are you passing them ?

Comment: i mean to say how to pas this latitude as params

Comment: Very easy, i am assuming that right now you are passing it, as parameters, so do one thing, create a new parameter in your getID() method , and create one new static array of size 2 in this class file, and pass that array while calling getID() method

Comment: Sorry but i am confused..as u can see i am passing latitude to my getid() method and passing params as  param = new NameValuePair();
            param.setName("lat");
            param.setValue(lat);
            params[9] = param;
is this wrong?

Comment: when you are creating an array with size 8 that means you can access it from 0 to 7, and here are you are accessing 9th element, that is the wrong thing.

Comment: got a clear picture...and i changed the my arraysize...now itz working ...thanks a lot